# How can python recognize : in linux command using os.popen?

Tags: python

```
site_name = os.popen('cat /home/xmp/distribution/sites.conf|awk -F ":" '{print $1}'')
SITE_NAME = site_name.read().replace('\n', '')
```

when I'm doing `print SITE_NAME` it shows me the whole data written in file and does not recognize `":"` 
and `{print $1}`

so how i correct this?

thanks,

Comment: Read the file and parse the string in `python`.  There's no reason to fall back on `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would skip the external processes altogether:

```
with open("/home/xmp/distribution/sites.conf", "rt") as txtfile:
    for line in txtfile:
        fields = line.split(':')
        print fields[0]
```

Comment: Can i put all this with open("/home/xmp/distribution/sites.conf", "rt") as txtfile:
    for line in txtfile:
        fields = line.split(':')
        print fields[0] in some variable??

Comment: You already have the values in fields that you could save if you need.

Answer (score 1):

If your `awk` script is not more complex than that, you might want to fall back on a pure Python implementation as mentioned elsewhere.

**Otherwise, an easy fix** is to replace the outer-most `'` with `"""` :

```
site_name = os.popen("""cat /home/xmp/distribution/sites.conf|awk -F ":" '{print $1}'""")
SITE_NAME = site_name.read().replace('\n', '')
```

This should work without the need to escape the inner-most `'`s

As a side note, `cat`is useless here:

```
site_name = os.popen("""awk -F ":" '{print $1}' /home/xmp/distribution/sites.conf""")
```

and to simplify a bit:

```
site_name = os.popen("awk -F ':' '{print $1}' /home/xmp/distribution/sites.conf")
```

Comment: mgmt_ip_1 = os.popen("""cat /home/xmp/distribution/sites.conf|awk -F ":" '{print $2}'""")
MGMT_IP_1 = site_name.read().replace('\n', '') WHY WHEN I DO IT TO SECOND FIELD IT DOSENT WORK?

Comment: Works fine here with the 'samara' example you provided in another comment

Answer (score 0):

I cannot clearly see what you did, but it seems that

```
os.popen('cat /home/xmp/distribution/sites.conf|awk -F ":" '{print $1}'')
```

is definitely wrong syntax, so it shouldn't run at all.

Inside the string, the `'`s should be replaced with `\'`s.

Even better it would be if you would get used to using the `subprocess` module instead of `os.popen()`.

```
import subprocess
sp = subprocess.Popen('cat /home/xmp/distribution/sites.conf|awk -F ":" \'{print $1}'\', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
SITE_NAME = sp.stdout.read().replace('\n', '')
sp.wait()
```

Even better would be to do

```
with open("/home/xmp/distribution/sites.conf", "r") as txtfile:
    sp = subprocess.Popen(['awk', '-F', ':', '{print $1}'], stdin=txtfile, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    SITE_NAME = sp.stdout.read().replace('\n', '')
    sp.wait()
```

Comment: just to clarify when I'm doing the command in bash: 
cat /home/xmp/distribution/sites.conf|awk -F ":" '{print $1}'
it will take the first field from the file, 
the file sites.conf seems like this: Samara:10.141.110.4:10.141.110.20 so the output:
will be Samara, so how can i do it in python with os.popen?

Comment: @user3013012 As I wrote above, with the `'` in the string replaced by `\'`. An alternative can be to use `"""` style strings: `"""cat /home/xmp/distribution/sites.conf|awk -F ":" '{print $1}'"""`.